# The method 'X' is not a property accessor (Linq / LinqToSql)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using `LinqToSql` classes in an ASP.NET website and let's say I have an entity named `Testimonials`. Two pages utilise this type - the first being a list of all existing `Testimonial` records and the second being an add / editor with which to manage the records.

On the first page we use a simple query, for example:

```
Public Function GetTestimonials() As IQueryable(Of Testimonial)
    Return From testimonial In Context.Testimonials Select testimonial
End Function
```

This allows population a `DataGrid` with the returned items, however on the add / editor page we alter the query ever so slightly:

```
Public Function FindTestimonial(ByVal id As Integer) As Testimonial
    Return (From testimonial In Context.Testimonials Where testimonial.ID = id
            Select testimonial).FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

This query dies, prior to even trying to populate anything, with the following message:

```
The method 'Testimonial.add_PropertyChanged' is not a property accessor
```

I have pretty much identical methods for other data objects which have been and still are executing just fine. One immediate difference I can think of is that this table has been recently updated in the database, removed from the `dbml` designer and re-added to the `dbml` designer. None of the other tables have undergone this process for some time.

***Why is this exception occurring and how can I configure my project appropriately to correct the issue?***

I'm going to look into myself now (obviously), but an initial Google search didn't show up anything which could deter me from heading here, and to be quite honest I don't have time to figure it all out and understand *why* - that'll have to come when I find the answer!

EDIT:

The code making the call to `FindTestimonial` is as follows (I can't see the link to the red herring suggested by Gabe, however, I'm not the one with the answers in this predicament):

```
Private Sub PopulateView()
    If (TestimonialId > 0) Then
        Dim testimonialService = DataServices.GetService(Of TestimonialService)()
        Dim testimonial = testimonialService.FindTestimonial(TestimonialId)
        If (testimonial IsNot Nothing) Then
            NameTextBox.Text = testimonial.Name
            LocationTextBox.Text = testimonial.Location
            MessageTextBox.Text = testimonial.Message
            PublishDateTextBox.Text = testimonial.PublishDate
            IsActiveCheckBox.Checked = testimonial.IsActive
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property TestimonialId() As Integer
    Get
        Return Domain.Web.UI.QueryString.GetValue(Web.UI.QueryStringParameter.TestimonialId)
    End Get
End Property
```

*Where `DataServices` is simply a list of our available data service classes which are preloaded with a page (such code works flawlessly throughout multiple projects, so I can't see the problem rising that far up) and the `GetService` can simply be translated into newing up an instance.*

Comment: The query is a red herring. Your problem is that something is trying to hook up to a `PropertyChanged` event on the `Testimonial` instance returned by the query. You'll have to post the code where `FindTestimonial` is called.

Comment: the term "is not a property accessor" in relation to linq 2 sql may help others solve this ... leaving it around for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the solution was as simple as follows:

- Remove the `Testimonial` class from the `dbml` designer
- Save all and then build all
- Drag the `Testimonial` table from `Server Explorer` afresh
- Save all and then build all

Although this resolved my issue, it doesn't tell me or help me deduce *why* this occurred. If anyone would like to elaborate further on that subject then I won't be ignorant of learning the facts, so please do so.